# Distinguishing overlapped signals(A-scan time Vs Amplitude in Ultrasonic Testing, NDT) using wavelets

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I am doing a project in which two or more defects are placed together and I am receiving echoes, such that the signals obtained (A-scan Ultrasonic testing, NDT, time Vs Amplitude) are overlapped one over the other.

how can I distinguish or show them individually using  wavelets in Matlab software?

Please at least tell me the outline of the code so that each signal show its individual properties. A brief outline line by line will be helpful.

Comment: Are they the same frequency? did you try filtering with Band-pass filters?